# Are SharpDX's ContextDirect2D methods different from XNA's SpriteBatch?

Tags: xna, spritebatch, sharpdx

I'm migrating from XNA to SharpDX in Win8. I noticed [this](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct2d1-devicecontext-drawbitmap) `DrawBitmap` call in one of the samples.

Is this different in some shape, way or form from XNA's `SpriteBatch`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are absolutely different.

The [SharpDX method](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct2d1-devicecontext-drawbitmap) you linked to is a wrapper around the [native Direct2D `DrawBitmap` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj841146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); SharpDX is primarily just an interoperability API that provides a wrapper around native functions (excluding it's "toolkit" APIs).

[XNA's `SpriteBatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.aspx) is a high-level wrapper around Direct3D drawing primitives (vertex buffers, textures, shaders) that provides an easy way to draw sprites.

You can use both interfaces to draw 2D sprites on a screen. Used properly you can probably achieve performance parity. However, they are not interchangeable interfaces.